# How to put triple qoutes around existing string variable?

Tags: string, python-3.x, string-literals

Let's say I have this variable:

```
st='MI'
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
st=''' 'MI' '''
```

to use it in a SQL command. 
What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean `" 'MI' "`, which you can do that by a simple formatting. `"'{}'".format(st)`

Comment: The only way to edit literals is with a text editor. I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: @Kasramvd: that did it. If you want to post as an answer, I'll mark accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tripleor single quoting are just ways of typing strings into source code files.

Once your program is running, your string is already a string, and there is no need to make any cnversion to use it as a parameter to a SQL driver function call.

What you may want i to have a string with an SQL statement that itself contains various (single or double) quote characters. If that is typed in your Python source code file, you can type the triple-quote straight. If you are getting these SQL statements  from elsewhere, they are already strings, as I said above.

Now, there are a few instances in which you have a string in a running Python program, or a Python interactive session, that you would like printed, so that you can paste it directly in source code. For these cases you can try the "unicode_escape"  codec (and recode it to text so that it does not double your backslashes:

```
In [56]: print("\n".encode("unicode_escape").decode("utf-8"))
\n
```